# AsyncTask in Mono for Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-asynctask

I just recently started using Mono for Android and I am trying to consume WCF services using SOAP. I've consumed some basic SOAP services using just Android, but I'm using Mono for Android now and I'm not exactly sure of the syntax for Asynctask. Does anyone know the proper syntax for Asynctask in Mono for Android.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation](http://docs.mono-android.net/?link=T%3aAndroid.OS.AsyncTask#).

The syntax is similar to the java syntax. `AsyncTask<T1, T2, T3>`  where `T1` is the parameters type, `T2` is the progress parameters type and `T3` is the result type, or just `AsyncTask<Params, Porgress, Result>`.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, thank you. That documentation was eluding me.